# “Too few non-missing observations” in ARIMA Forecasting in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm having trouble with a ARIMA Forecasting script in R due to a "too few non-missing observations" error, and was hoping to solicit some assistance after unsuccessfully troubleshooting it myself.

My exact script is fairly simple, and reads like this:

```
library(forecast) 
SalesData <- aggregate(Revenue~SalesCategory+Month, data = dataset, FUN = sum)
SalesForecast <- ts(SalesData$Revenue, start = 0, freq = 12)    
fit <- arima(log(SalesForecast), c(1, 1, 0),
             seasonal = list(order = c(1, 1, 0),     
             period = 12))
pred <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 12)    
Adjusted.pred <- (2.718^pred$pred)   
ts.plot(SalesForecast,Adjusted.pred, log = "y", ylab= "Revenue", 
     lty = c(1,3),main = "Forecasted Revenue", xlab ="Fiscal Year Months")
```

It's also worth noting that my sales data is seasonal and stretches from July 2013 to August 2016. During that time period, some products were deprecated, or newly added. There's also periods where a product was deprecated for several months before being re-prioritized, which I think may be root cause of the issue.

Appreciate any and all assistance or guidance on what may be a pretty basic question.

Best,
Jake

```
Month   Revenue SalesCategory
6/1/2014    872.446483  Orange
7/1/2014    27415.60511 Orange
8/1/2014    74292.08374 Orange
9/1/2014    120817.748  Orange
10/1/2014   163667.9254 Orange
11/1/2014   361728.9997 Orange
12/1/2014   287626.8962 Orange
1/1/2015    256132.8191 Orange
2/1/2015    281025.9382 Orange
3/1/2015    622223.3008 Orange
4/1/2015    354815.5095 Orange
5/1/2015    265576.7564 Orange
6/1/2015    360826.4308 Orange
7/1/2013    588025.0006 Blue
8/1/2013    652617.4266 Blue
9/1/2013    650277.7455 Blue
10/1/2013   724311.5886 Blue
11/1/2013   674752.8929 Blue
12/1/2013   871649.6068 Blue
1/1/2014    422410.6554 Blue
2/1/2014    414430.5516 Blue
3/1/2014    399161.6918 Blue
4/1/2014    370860.6502 Blue
5/1/2014    541905.025  Blue
6/1/2014    516731.6737 Blue
7/1/2014    385695.9653 Blue
8/1/2014    449845.4301 Blue
9/1/2014    293212.8969 Blue
10/1/2014   196985.2955 Blue
11/1/2014   230369.0426 Blue
12/1/2014   375275.1204 Blue
1/1/2015    128554.7657 Blue
2/1/2015    136430.5672 Blue
3/1/2015    136033.0716 Blue
4/1/2015    125635.0309 Blue
5/1/2015    152383.778  Blue
6/1/2015    11891.35223 Blue
7/1/2015    10.78232    Blue
8/1/2015    8.600054    Blue
9/1/2015    6.125262    Blue
10/1/2015   3.688184    Blue
11/1/2015   2.378511    Blue
12/1/2015   0.8949777   Blue
1/1/2016    0.1565892   Blue
2/1/2016    0.1817317   Blue
3/1/2016    0.07015 Blue
4/1/2016    0.0327  Blue
5/1/2016    496.01171   Blue
6/1/2016    0   Blue
7/1/2016    0   Blue
8/1/2016    0   Blue
10/1/2014   22559.14026 Black
11/1/2014   113413.3118 Black
12/1/2014   355487.1326 Black
1/1/2015    475413.4705 Black
2/1/2015    541123.0262 Black
3/1/2015    658523.3192 Black
4/1/2015    539569.5451 Black
5/1/2015    537714.0264 Black
6/1/2015    540749.4187 Black
7/1/2015    0   Black
2/1/2014    1045.282484 Gray
3/1/2014    0.01048 Gray
4/1/2014    0   Gray
5/1/2014    0   Gray
12/1/2015   0.4567944   Gray
1/1/2016    67.2964458  Gray
2/1/2016    65.2405035  Gray
3/1/2016    38.7794443  Gray
7/1/2013    103454.2354 White
8/1/2013    171370.7464 White
9/1/2013    283079.2564 White
10/1/2013   424687.7054 White
11/1/2013   612376.0585 White
12/1/2013   945304.5281 White
1/1/2014    341919.2179 White
2/1/2014    478848.2671 White
3/1/2014    774880.0632 White
4/1/2014    686531.079  White
5/1/2014    572505.1634 White
6/1/2014    663797.2645 White
7/1/2014    430098.5142 White
8/1/2014    346898.352  White
9/1/2014    353184.9587 White
10/1/2014   161663.4499 White
11/1/2014   216238.9023 White
12/1/2014   357995.1503 White
1/1/2015    167716.8869 White
2/1/2015    99321.08561 White
3/1/2015    90474.87056 White
4/1/2015    54755.43886 White
5/1/2015    44959.11504 White
6/1/2015    60601.33456 White
7/1/2015    28816.2135  White
8/1/2015    23525.2123  White
9/1/2015    22023.87244 White
10/1/2015   500.628171  White
11/1/2015   11.740983   White
12/1/2015   1.4085756   White
1/1/2016    0.1890511   White
2/1/2016    0.073819    White
3/1/2016    0.1150476   White
4/1/2016    0.0050657   White
5/1/2016    0   White
6/1/2016    0   White
7/1/2016    0   White
8/1/2016    0   White
7/1/2013    485.4243975 Red
8/1/2013    3.39293577  Red
9/1/2013    5.42042393  Red
10/1/2013   8.174868    Red
11/1/2013   8.86948286  Red
12/1/2013   7.27585039  Red
1/1/2014    153.964892  Red
2/1/2014    62.817221   Red
3/1/2014    229.942113  Red
4/1/2014    66.312332   Red
5/1/2014    107.612302  Red
6/1/2014    449.725595  Red
7/1/2014    1652.623186 Red
8/1/2014    2635.510635 Red
9/1/2014    876.361173  Red
10/1/2014   836.938981  Red
11/1/2014   1843.838808 Red
12/1/2014   1918.480787 Red
1/1/2015    0.002048    Red
2/1/2015    0.001432    Red
3/1/2015    0.001059    Red
4/1/2015    0.001613    Red
5/1/2015    0.00135 Red
8/1/2015    0.001   Red
2/1/2016    0.0018374   Red
9/1/2014    0.002087    Yellow
10/1/2014   0   Yellow
11/1/2014   0   Yellow
12/1/2014   0   Yellow
1/1/2015    0   Yellow
2/1/2015    0   Yellow
3/1/2015    242.63139   Yellow
4/1/2015    393.517539  Yellow
5/1/2015    551.942596  Yellow
6/1/2015    544.338007  Yellow
7/1/2015    0   Yellow
8/1/2015    0   Yellow
9/1/2015    0   Yellow
10/1/2015   0   Yellow
11/1/2015   0   Yellow
12/1/2015   232.3945437 Yellow
1/1/2016    187.0862765 Yellow
2/1/2016    0   Yellow
3/1/2016    0   Yellow
4/1/2016    0   Yellow
5/1/2016    0   Yellow
6/1/2016    0   Yellow
7/1/2016    0   Yellow
8/1/2016    0   Yellow
7/1/2013    6.57399404  Teal
8/1/2013    4.94998805  Teal
9/1/2013    9.00774152  Teal
10/1/2013   9.49746566  Teal
11/1/2013   11.31726121 Teal
12/1/2013   9.68909605  Teal
1/1/2014    4.378742    Teal
2/1/2014    4.268959    Teal
3/1/2014    7.889073    Teal
4/1/2014    1.642041    Teal
7/1/2013    0.07857562  Green
8/1/2013    0.02407967  Green
9/1/2013    0.07290788  Green
10/1/2013   0.08540275  Green
11/1/2013   0.05424165  Green
12/1/2013   0.03448481  Green
1/1/2014    0.019639    Green
2/1/2014    0.027405    Green
3/1/2014    0.056806    Green
4/1/2014    0.031718    Green
5/1/2014    0.01583 Green
9/1/2014    6.092477    Maroon
10/1/2014   2.125143    Maroon
11/1/2014   20.971927   Maroon
12/1/2014   5.884376    Maroon
1/1/2015    3.470562    Maroon
2/1/2015    585.412606  Maroon
3/1/2015    22686.97242 Maroon
4/1/2015    97067.40143 Maroon
5/1/2015    121869.2472 Maroon
6/1/2015    135214.5345 Maroon
7/1/2015    89336.47872 Maroon
8/1/2015    92444.65462 Maroon
9/1/2015    132310.2372 Maroon
10/1/2015   115558.5213 Maroon
11/1/2015   162780.6291 Maroon
12/1/2015   163722.6052 Maroon
1/1/2016    104097.89   Maroon
2/1/2016    80201.75931 Maroon
3/1/2016    103797.0382 Maroon
4/1/2016    81507.72535 Maroon
5/1/2016    107493.1832 Maroon
6/1/2016    115225.8871 Maroon
7/1/2016    100779.4421 Maroon
8/1/2016    161750.5709 Maroon
7/1/2013    942744.6418 Burnt Orange
8/1/2013    1008340.789 Burnt Orange
9/1/2013    889803.7261 Burnt Orange
10/1/2013   656217.2015 Burnt Orange
11/1/2013   952755.3652 Burnt Orange
12/1/2013   375981.9599 Burnt Orange
1/1/2014    1209321.384 Burnt Orange
2/1/2014    614167.0686 Burnt Orange
3/1/2014    732154.595  Burnt Orange
4/1/2014    1147855.821 Burnt Orange
5/1/2014    1279385.815 Burnt Orange
6/1/2014    1131145.804 Burnt Orange
7/1/2014    1609763.532 Burnt Orange
8/1/2014    1700764.693 Burnt Orange
9/1/2014    1474718.508 Burnt Orange
10/1/2014   1242259.623 Burnt Orange
11/1/2014   1458237.902 Burnt Orange
12/1/2014   1659004.632 Burnt Orange
1/1/2015    3653607.043 Burnt Orange
2/1/2015    2868265.459 Burnt Orange
3/1/2015    3745311.011 Burnt Orange
4/1/2015    4083569.698 Burnt Orange
5/1/2015    3538107.069 Burnt Orange
6/1/2015    5663504.216 Burnt Orange
7/1/2015    5930931.827 Burnt Orange
8/1/2015    6106445.836 Burnt Orange
9/1/2015    7059156.619 Burnt Orange
10/1/2015   9506117.045 Burnt Orange
11/1/2015   7705094.509 Burnt Orange
12/1/2015   9461014.627 Burnt Orange
1/1/2016    9139009.685 Burnt Orange
2/1/2016    6679580.978 Burnt Orange
3/1/2016    8733237.033 Burnt Orange
4/1/2016    7139955.952 Burnt Orange
5/1/2016    8094093.819 Burnt Orange
6/1/2016    9255422.036 Burnt Orange
7/1/2016    9234943.809 Burnt Orange
8/1/2016    9025449.124 Burnt Orange
7/1/2013    0.00091391  Eggshell
9/1/2013    7.69E-05    Eggshell
10/1/2013   0.0003914   Eggshell
11/1/2013   0.00106852  Eggshell
5/1/2014    0.00027 Eggshell
10/1/2014   9600.611335 Eggshell
11/1/2014   39213.39315 Eggshell
12/1/2014   49611.47325 Eggshell
1/1/2015    39488.54573 Eggshell
2/1/2015    40038.75978 Eggshell
3/1/2015    57500.30278 Eggshell
4/1/2015    58967.08286 Eggshell
5/1/2015    119418.2945 Eggshell
6/1/2015    197875.903  Eggshell
7/1/2015    208291.0205 Eggshell
8/1/2015    199556.3633 Eggshell
9/1/2015    181935.77   Eggshell
10/1/2015   187274.8072 Eggshell
11/1/2015   265091.7069 Eggshell
12/1/2015   235995.82   Eggshell
1/1/2016    162704.3921 Eggshell
2/1/2016    145915.697  Eggshell
3/1/2016    207327.3106 Eggshell
4/1/2016    142476.5606 Eggshell
5/1/2016    185868.0071 Eggshell
6/1/2016    225289.5468 Eggshell
7/1/2016    244246.1984 Eggshell
8/1/2016    244572.2056 Eggshell
7/1/2013    2301622.029 Navy
8/1/2013    2146835.127 Navy
9/1/2013    2038147.979 Navy
10/1/2013   2602763.799 Navy
11/1/2013   2120077.201 Navy
12/1/2013   2100953.325 Navy
1/1/2014    1999920.1   Navy
2/1/2014    1703563.642 Navy
3/1/2014    1669073.378 Navy
4/1/2014    2305637.784 Navy
5/1/2014    2634698.51  Navy
6/1/2014    1687723.38  Navy
7/1/2014    2084579.625 Navy
8/1/2014    2350005.581 Navy
9/1/2014    1573464.772 Navy
10/1/2014   1951579.145 Navy
11/1/2014   3237249.833 Navy
12/1/2014   4171508.264 Navy
1/1/2015    4393928.246 Navy
2/1/2015    5027010.258 Navy
3/1/2015    7353014.705 Navy
4/1/2015    6818122.133 Navy
5/1/2015    7496166.93  Navy
6/1/2015    8110138.619 Navy
7/1/2015    6613409.673 Navy
8/1/2015    7700758.114 Navy
9/1/2015    8873506.303 Navy
10/1/2015   8607743.379 Navy
11/1/2015   8402456.283 Navy
12/1/2015   9140438.689 Navy
1/1/2016    8275840.634 Navy
2/1/2016    7395649.898 Navy
3/1/2016    7866524.705 Navy
4/1/2016    8085877.718 Navy
5/1/2016    9916552.566 Navy
6/1/2016    10679960.28 Navy
7/1/2016    9633510.896 Navy
8/1/2016    9676609.089 Navy
7/1/2013    307.5433145 Purple
8/1/2013    278.1919963 Purple
9/1/2013    287.8129872 Purple
10/1/2013   398.9677103 Purple
11/1/2013   519.0542504 Purple
12/1/2013   635.7302839 Purple
1/1/2014    476.532828  Purple
2/1/2014    235.580273  Purple
3/1/2014    263.450333  Purple
4/1/2014    305.085377  Purple
5/1/2014    524.16711   Purple
6/1/2014    810.060485  Purple
7/1/2014    1010.30702  Purple
8/1/2014    1129.007214 Purple
9/1/2014    1255.477696 Purple
10/1/2014   2.923276    Purple
11/1/2014   0.008834    Purple
12/1/2014   0.004957    Purple
1/1/2015    0.000673    Purple
2/1/2015    0.000973    Purple
3/1/2015    0.001761    Purple
4/1/2015    0   Purple
5/1/2015    0   Purple
6/1/2015    0.000257    Purple
7/1/2015    0.001083    Purple
8/1/2015    0.000198    Purple
9/1/2015    0   Purple
10/1/2015   0.001564    Purple
11/1/2015   0.004523    Purple
12/1/2015   0.0086669   Purple
1/1/2016    0.0025812   Purple
2/1/2016    0.0291021   Purple
3/1/2016    0.0047537   Purple
7/1/2013    0   Violet
11/1/2013   39981.47669 Pink
12/1/2013   292326.5036 Pink
1/1/2014    404725.4259 Pink
2/1/2014    425130.3693 Pink
3/1/2014    614204.0834 Pink
4/1/2014    625968.1274 Pink
5/1/2014    831838.5996 Pink
6/1/2014    1078311.547 Pink
7/1/2014    1180858.811 Pink
8/1/2014    1559672.695 Pink
9/1/2014    1665072.057 Pink
10/1/2014   2221061.833 Pink
11/1/2014   2421959.818 Pink
12/1/2014   2361507.542 Pink
1/1/2015    3438545.036 Pink
2/1/2015    4781433.951 Pink
3/1/2015    5580747.858 Pink
4/1/2015    6009637.904 Pink
5/1/2015    6371627.215 Pink
6/1/2015    8011311.62  Pink
7/1/2015    8377299.761 Pink
8/1/2015    7955153.098 Pink
9/1/2015    8433538.874 Pink
10/1/2015   8949395.599 Pink
11/1/2015   9243816.7   Pink
12/1/2015   10195777.34 Pink
1/1/2016    8187700.993 Pink
2/1/2016    8637261.85  Pink
3/1/2016    9638219.75  Pink
4/1/2016    8915953.669 Pink
5/1/2016    10642506.11 Pink
6/1/2016    10080321.64 Pink
7/1/2016    9666473.977 Pink
8/1/2016    9213704.343 Pink
9/1/2014    0   Brown
10/1/2014   1475.734616 Brown
11/1/2014   10034.69818 Brown
12/1/2014   26777.75776 Brown
1/1/2015    20410.24773 Brown
2/1/2015    9221.681913 Brown
3/1/2015    0   Brown
4/1/2015    0   Brown
5/1/2015    0   Brown
6/1/2015    5423.614942 Brown
7/1/2015    4036.495819 Brown
8/1/2015    393.553677  Brown
9/1/2015    696.459359  Brown
10/1/2015   727.303977  Brown
11/1/2015   695.417502  Brown
12/1/2015   582.9390027 Brown
1/1/2016    312.1278448 Brown
2/1/2016    274.445592  Brown
3/1/2016    63.3483473  Brown
4/1/2016    63.7311201  Brown
5/1/2016    42.7281731  Brown
6/1/2016    82.7233785  Brown
7/1/2016    145.0530579 Brown
8/1/2016    97.7986379  Brown
7/1/2013    235605.6914 Cyan
8/1/2013    174622.2269 Cyan
9/1/2013    120922.6272 Cyan
10/1/2013   196018.4043 Cyan
11/1/2013   288439.6165 Cyan
12/1/2013   510395.0504 Cyan
1/1/2014    433112.6638 Cyan
2/1/2014    749648.1663 Cyan
3/1/2014    737664.4143 Cyan
4/1/2014    715366.6502 Cyan
5/1/2014    686836.1374 Cyan
6/1/2014    817068.5427 Cyan
7/1/2014    719814.6628 Cyan
8/1/2014    689273.6975 Cyan
9/1/2014    770560.6247 Cyan
10/1/2014   839842.8723 Cyan
11/1/2014   851839.7291 Cyan
12/1/2014   863758.5806 Cyan
1/1/2015    590566.349  Cyan
2/1/2015    753776.062  Cyan
3/1/2015    917969.4341 Cyan
4/1/2015    965800.3896 Cyan
5/1/2015    1309092.636 Cyan
6/1/2015    1609904.565 Cyan
7/1/2015    1749263.709 Cyan
8/1/2015    1619434.314 Cyan
9/1/2015    2247759.634 Cyan
10/1/2015   2106483.207 Cyan
11/1/2015   2487187.756 Cyan
12/1/2015   2978032.534 Cyan
1/1/2016    1549134.595 Cyan
2/1/2016    1318296.68  Cyan
3/1/2016    1367194.991 Cyan
4/1/2016    632784.8528 Cyan
5/1/2016    1097796.288 Cyan
6/1/2016    1381051.439 Cyan
7/1/2016    1362576.1   Cyan
8/1/2016    1231926.391 Cyan
11/1/2014   16068.34495 Beige
12/1/2014   31279.44024 Beige
1/1/2015    0   Beige
2/1/2015    9519.657647 Beige
3/1/2015    84356.80876 Beige
4/1/2015    27815.33338 Beige
5/1/2015    8910.925482 Beige
6/1/2015    23344.09193 Beige
7/1/2015    7102.864199 Beige
8/1/2015    10362.03059 Beige
9/1/2015    6908.249406 Beige
10/1/2015   2394.662506 Beige
11/1/2015   6175.75741  Beige
12/1/2015   53700.08375 Beige
1/1/2016    15125.61961 Beige
2/1/2016    27.3084663  Beige
3/1/2016    0   Beige
4/1/2016    0   Beige
7/1/2015    501293.1482 Ivory
8/1/2015    410481.8783 Ivory
9/1/2015    525918.0836 Ivory
10/1/2015   542000.9188 Ivory
11/1/2015   594542.3264 Ivory
12/1/2015   768509.7769 Ivory
1/1/2016    443500.4486 Ivory
2/1/2016    324006.8477 Ivory
3/1/2016    239338.2974 Ivory
4/1/2016    273324.6036 Ivory
5/1/2016    409295.775  Ivory
6/1/2016    700378.9515 Ivory
7/1/2016    401957.6123 Ivory
8/1/2016    447519.7246 Ivory
7/1/2015    1126000.497 Pearl
8/1/2015    951537.4082 Pearl
9/1/2015    786532.6702 Pearl
10/1/2015   841154.3312 Pearl
11/1/2015   905319.6045 Pearl
12/1/2015   956852.9913 Pearl
1/1/2016    789439.4999 Pearl
2/1/2016    674985.6733 Pearl
3/1/2016    574696.5649 Pearl
4/1/2016    518249.4672 Pearl
5/1/2016    510927.4347 Pearl
6/1/2016    595487.3358 Pearl
7/1/2016    466223.3599 Pearl
8/1/2016    579063.8057 Pearl
7/1/2013    12145.51106 Seashell
8/1/2013    13982.8085  Seashell
9/1/2013    12953.67461 Seashell
10/1/2013   10982.11483 Seashell
11/1/2013   6659.117341 Seashell
12/1/2013   8603.827681 Seashell
1/1/2014    5613.780341 Seashell
2/1/2014    5704.915496 Seashell
3/1/2014    5447.09463  Seashell
4/1/2014    4906.073997 Seashell
5/1/2014    5479.032855 Seashell
6/1/2014    5042.746803 Seashell
7/1/2014    3847.818508 Seashell
8/1/2014    5734.458982 Seashell
9/1/2014    6704.587544 Seashell
10/1/2014   7647.074472 Seashell
11/1/2014   6196.864341 Seashell
12/1/2014   7559.830528 Seashell
1/1/2015    4774.247942 Seashell
2/1/2015    5755.55747  Seashell
3/1/2015    9360.679541 Seashell
4/1/2015    8277.280102 Seashell
5/1/2015    9337.191566 Seashell
6/1/2015    9434.954193 Seashell
7/1/2015    7901.575492 Seashell
8/1/2015    7505.799573 Seashell
9/1/2015    8586.209186 Seashell
10/1/2015   9199.235295 Seashell
11/1/2015   10814.8075  Seashell
12/1/2015   10431.21367 Seashell
1/1/2016    4813.805788 Seashell
2/1/2016    4798.322306 Seashell
3/1/2016    6250.045823 Seashell
4/1/2016    4286.18379  Seashell
5/1/2016    4479.507199 Seashell
6/1/2016    24.9639029  Seashell
7/1/2016    0.0166208   Seashell
8/1/2016    0.010681    Seashell
9/1/2014    0.124513    Vanilla
10/1/2014   9386.679222 Vanilla
11/1/2014   62678.75641 Vanilla
12/1/2014   142998.4728 Vanilla
1/1/2015    88825.31542 Vanilla
2/1/2015    63402.49197 Vanilla
3/1/2015    119038.8152 Vanilla
4/1/2015    79002.37486 Vanilla
5/1/2015    71813.21074 Vanilla
6/1/2015    73068.08446 Vanilla
7/1/2015    58905.05844 Vanilla
8/1/2015    92645.82262 Vanilla
9/1/2015    220728.7663 Vanilla
10/1/2015   180677.913  Vanilla
11/1/2015   255986.6834 Vanilla
12/1/2015   282965.9907 Vanilla
1/1/2016    178225.1344 Vanilla
2/1/2016    176192.8082 Vanilla
3/1/2016    157988.8095 Vanilla
4/1/2016    154261.6344 Vanilla
5/1/2016    382507.0115 Vanilla
6/1/2016    512505.9376 Vanilla
7/1/2016    436928.8583 Vanilla
8/1/2016    478834.7415 Vanilla
9/1/2014    0   Taupe
10/1/2014   0   Taupe
11/1/2014   0   Taupe
12/1/2014   0   Taupe
1/1/2015    0   Taupe
2/1/2015    0   Taupe
3/1/2015    0   Taupe
4/1/2015    0   Taupe
5/1/2015    0   Taupe
6/1/2015    0   Taupe
7/1/2015    0   Taupe
8/1/2015    0   Taupe
9/1/2015    0   Taupe
10/1/2015   0   Taupe
11/1/2015   769.552092  Taupe
12/1/2015   777.2842088 Taupe
1/1/2016    471.9138592 Taupe
2/1/2016    182.6314588 Taupe
3/1/2016    427.5499355 Taupe
4/1/2016    376.1232696 Taupe
5/1/2016    457.9525202 Taupe
6/1/2016    557.8859334 Taupe
7/1/2016    794.7244974 Taupe
8/1/2016    741.0160445 Taupe
7/1/2013    165887.3494 Silver
8/1/2013    182241.6242 Silver
9/1/2013    171394.3484 Silver
10/1/2013   213335.5572 Silver
11/1/2013   227834.7215 Silver
12/1/2013   293496.5852 Silver
1/1/2014    134654.95   Silver
2/1/2014    115044.6029 Silver
3/1/2014    183967.1646 Silver
4/1/2014    184941.7302 Silver
5/1/2014    204545.9821 Silver
6/1/2014    215482.2549 Silver
7/1/2014    173641.8665 Silver
8/1/2014    181926.7956 Silver
9/1/2014    164437.0225 Silver
10/1/2014   215872.1443 Silver
11/1/2014   238221.9449 Silver
12/1/2014   266033.0641 Silver
1/1/2015    144658.1936 Silver
2/1/2015    172184.7977 Silver
3/1/2015    278659.7936 Silver
4/1/2015    225761.0271 Silver
5/1/2015    265556.131  Silver
6/1/2015    269989.4074 Silver
7/1/2015    180198.494  Silver
8/1/2015    219580.0754 Silver
9/1/2015    232183.1621 Silver
10/1/2015   231797.2037 Silver
11/1/2015   239490.8623 Silver
12/1/2015   248202.5771 Silver
1/1/2016    133143.5545 Silver
2/1/2016    127801.4308 Silver
3/1/2016    159318.4877 Silver
4/1/2016    140068.919  Silver
5/1/2016    130573.4838 Silver
6/1/2016    81448.51397 Silver
7/1/2016    134755.0469 Silver
8/1/2016    168724.2546 Silver
```